# which is less resource intensive: wrapping multiple divs with an extra html element, or styling several unwrapped elements individually?

Tags: html, css, styling

Ok, I've been taught that you only should use a wrapper `<div></div>` if it is absolutely necessary, since creating an unneeded element in the DOM wastes resources.

However, let's say you have 5 child elements which all need a left margin of 10%. would writing the css for each one be less intensive than making a new div?

So the code would look something like this:

## scenario 1: Wrapper

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='div1'></div>
    <div class='div2'></div>
    <div class='div3'></div>
    <div class='div4'></div>
    <div class='div5'></div>
</div>



.wrapper{
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

## scenario 2: No Wrapper and all elements styles with one css entry

```
    <div class='div1'></div>
    <div class='div2'></div>
    <div class='div3'></div>
    <div class='div4'></div>
    <div class='div5'></div>



.div1,
.div2,
.div3,
.div4,
.div5{
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

## scenario 3: No Wrapper and the elements already have styling

```
<div class='div1'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
<div class='div3'></div>
<div class='div4'></div>
<div class='div5'></div>



.div1{
    margin-left: 10px
}
.div2{
    margin-left: 10px
    color: red
}
.div3{
    margin-left: 10px
    color: blue
}
.div4{
    margin-left: 10px
    color: white
}
.div5{
    margin-left: 10px
    color: green
}
```

Also, would the number of elements that need the same styling change your answer??

Thanks for your thoughts, I want to start forming good habits :)

Comment: My advice is to go the wrapper route. Most browsers are efficient enough with their resources that there will be virtually no difference in performance, and the wrapper route is the most readable IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better solution is:

HTML

```
<div class="div div--one"></div>
<div class="div div--two"></div>
<div class="div div--three"></div>
```

CSS

```
.div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.div--two {
  color: red;
}

.div--three {
  color: yellow;
}
```

This is obviously just an example.  Please do not name your classes 'div'.

Comment: I like it, and I'm naming my classes div just because you said that, Cheers!

Comment: Why, in the context of resource intensity, is this "better"?

Comment: @Alohci because by making the classes modular, you can share them across multiple elements on the site... Therefore reducing the amount of repeated code and one off styles. In this example you could just create helper classes to give margin and color. It's just a better way to write CSS.